# BlackBerry Facebook SDK. Simply log in (Java)

Tags: java, facebook, api, blackberry

I'm developing a game for BlackBerry curve 8520. It needs facebook integration so i just downloaded the SDK from [BLACK BERRY FACEBOOK SDK JAVA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/)

The documentation is very short, and this sdk doesn't have a webpage or whatever that can guide me through. How can i integrate this in my game? It's supposed to appear a popup to log in just like in web apps? or i need to do some extra work? I just can't make it work right.

Can you provide me a little example of this working and if it's possible, with the facebook developers app config? That would help me a lot.

Thank you guys in advance!

Francisco

Comment: Have you reviewed the sample that comes with the code - called Strawberry.